# Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type error when using redux toolkit with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i used redux-toolkit with typescript but the state in the reducer alway has type of any and it will get error.

```
 [export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
  // The `extraReducers` field lets the slice handle actions defined elsewhere,
  // including actions generated by createAsyncThunk or in other slices.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "idle";
        state.value += action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.rejected, (state) => {
        state.status = "failed";
      });
  },
});][1]
```

[image]

how can i fix that without set noImplicitAny is false

Comment: 1. Please include code examples as _formatted text_ as an [edit] so we can all stare at it. 2. What is your question? If there is an error message, include this as _formatted text_ in the question. 3. Did you search here and on the web for any messages you got? How do those results not answer this question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i had the same problem, and in my case it was an extension of vscode, [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly
v4.8.20220519](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next), I uninstalled it and the error is gone

I hope my answer helps, there are extensions that alter the code in some way

Comment: close VCS after uninstalling the extension, thanks for the anwer

Answer (score 2):

Create a type for initialState and use this type in the reducer, then the error will disappear.

```
type InitialStateType = {
  text: string;
}

const initialState: InitialStateType = {
  text: 'Initial message',
};

reducerName(state: InitialStateType, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
  // some important code
},
```

Answer (score -3):

You can just try and set your state type as any.

```js
(state: any)
```

This removes the error in the **Problems** tab while keeping the [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) extension enabled!

Answer (score -3):

Add "noImplicitAny": false, to your tsconfig.json

Comment: maybe it's late for the person who initially asked the question but might help others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this should not be done as it will allow your codebase to become a mess with tons of "any" types